# RequestDumperValve breaks POST request

Tags: coldfusion, redhat, coldfusion-9, jboss5.x

I have an historic ColdFusion 9 server running on top of JBoss 5.1 on Scientific Linux 6.2.
Every once in a while I see the error

```
2019-08-20 12:15:30,621 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[localhost].[/REDACTED].[CfmServlet]] (ajp-0.0.0.0-8009-8) Servlet.service() for servlet CfmServlet threw exception
javax.servlet.ServletException: ROOT CAUSE: 
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
        at coldfusion.filter.FormScope.parseQueryString(FormScope.java:375)
        at coldfusion.filter.FormScope.parsePostData(FormScope.java:346)
        at coldfusion.filter.FormScope.fillForm(FormScope.java:296)
        at coldfusion.filter.FusionContext.SymTab_initForRequest(FusionContext.java:377)
```

in the file `/var/log/jboss/server.log`

To find out what seems to be the problem I thought it's somehow possible to log the POST params JBoss received and is trying to prepare for ColdFusion to use. On the internet I read I should go to file `/opt/jboss/server/default/deploy/jbossweb.sar/server.xml` and uncomment the line `<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RequestDumperValve" />`.

Now, the params (cookie, header, POST etc.) are indeed logged into the `server.log` file. The ColdFusion server, however, does not do its task anymore. I open CFADMIN in the browser and enter the password. I'm not let in. I, again, see the log-on page. Same is true for my application. I see in the `server.log` file the parameters (username and password) are correct. They are logged in clear text.

There's a [story](https://rolfje.wordpress.com/2008/07/20/tomcat-utf-8-and-the-requestdumpervalve/) on the internet that describes how the RequestDumperValve destroys a request by applying wrong encoding. Does something like this happen to me? Are there other possibilities to log the POST params in JBoss?